# Kmsg timestamps are 500ms in the future

Tags: android, c++, linux

I am trying to keep track of when the system wakes and suspends (ideally when monotonic_time starts and stops) so that I can accurately correlate monotonic time-stamps to the realtime clock.

On android the first method that came to mind was to monitor kmsg for a wakeup message and use its timestamp as a fairly accurate mark. As I was unsure of the accuracy of this timestamp, I decided to log the current monotonic time as well.

The following code is running in a standalone executable

```
    while(true)
    {
        fgets(mLineBuffer, sizeof(mLineBuffer), mKmsgFile);

        //Find first space
        char * messageContent = strchr(mLineBuffer,' ');
        //Offset one to get character after space
        messageContent++;

        if (strncmp (messageContent,"Enabling non-boot CPUs ...",25) == 0 )
        {
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&mMono);
            std::cout << mLineBuffer;
            std::cout << std::to_string(mMono.tv_sec)  << "." << std::to_string(mMono.tv_nsec) << "\n";

        }

    }
```

I expected the time returned by clock_gettime to be at some point after the kmsg log timestamp, but instead it is anywhere from 600ms before to 200ms after.

```
<6>[226692.217017] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
    226691.681130889
```

-0.535886111

```
<6>[226692.626100] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
    226692.80532881
```

+0.17922881

```
<6>[226693.305535] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
    226692.803398747
```

-0.502136253

During this particular session, CLOCK_MONOTONIC consistently differed from the kmsg timestamp by roughly -500ms, only once flipping over to +179ms over the course of 10 wakeups. During a later session it was consistently off by -200ms.

The same consistent offset is present when monitoring all kmsg entries during normal operation (not suspending or waking). Perhaps returning from suspend occasionally delays my process long enough to produce a timestamp that is ahead of kmsg, resulting in the single +179ms difference.

CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE and CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW behave in the same manner.

Is this expected behavior? Does the kernel run on a separate monotonic clock?
Is there any other way to get wakeup/suspend times that correlate to monotonic time?

The ultimate goal is to use this information to help graph the contents of wakeup_sources over time, with a particular focus on activity immediately after waking. Though, if the kmsg timestamps are "incorrect", then the wakeup_sources ones probably are too.

Comment: what happens when the input line does not contain a space?  The posted code is not handling that condition.

Comment: The posted code is `C++`, not `C`  Please change the tag so the proper people will see the code.

Comment: this part of the characters being sent by the call the `cout`  "\n" is not correct.  it should be the characters: `endl`

Comment: the two timestamps are unrelated.  My suggestion: don't give them another thought

Comment: @user3629249 kmsg entries always have a space after the timestamp, no?

They should not be unrelated, but do indeed appear to be so.
It turns out the timestamps in wakeup_sources are normal monotonic time, so there's that I guess.